# Usage of implicit function theorem for $f(x,y)=x^2+2xy-y^2-a^2$

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, implicit-function-theorem

> Find the derivative of the following implicit function with the implicit function theorem:
>
> $$F(x,y)=x^2+2xy-y^2-a^2$$

---

My attempt for this task:
$$F(x,y)=0 \Leftrightarrow (x,y)=(a,0)$$

Derivate partial: 
$$\partial_x F(x,y)=2x+2y\\
\partial_y F(x,y)=2x-2y$$

Prove, if $\partial_y$ invertible:
$$\partial_y \text{invertible} \, \Leftrightarrow a \neq 0$$

So I get for the derivate:
$$f'(x_0,y_0)=-\left(\frac{x+y}{x-y}\right)$$

---

Is this the right and easiest way?

Comment: Is $(a,0)$ the only solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$F_x(x,y)=2(x+y),\qquad F_y(x,y)=2(x-y).$$ Thus as long as $F_y(x,y)\neq 0$, i.e. $x\neq y$ we have by the implicit function theorem: $$\frac{d y}{dx}=-\frac{F_x(x,y)}{F_y(x,y)}=-\frac{2(x+y)}{2(x-y)}=\frac{x+y}{y-x}.$$

---

Note in cases where $x=y$, we can instead find the derivative of $x$ with respect to $y$. As long as $F_x(x,y)\neq 0$, i.e. $x\neq -y$

$$\frac{d x}{dy}=-\frac{F_y(x,y)}{F_x(x,y)}=-\frac{2(x-y)}{2(x+y)}=\frac{y-x}{x+y}.$$

Comment: Yes, you're right I've made a sign mistake. Thanks! Is it important to have **all** solutions for $F(x,y)=0$?

Comment: You do not need to find any solutions to do the calculation. I was just curious why you wrote $F(x,y)=0 \Leftrightarrow (x,y)=(a,0)$. This is not actually true since there are other solutions to $F(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Oh, I see (but $(a,0)$ is one solution, isn't it?). I was not clear about this step either but it was a necessary thing for my professor.

Comment: Yes, it is one solution. Were you asked for the derivative of the implicit function at $(a,0)$? If so, you just need to plug it in to the formula above (assuming $a\neq 0$).

Comment: No, I was not. Okay, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

i have got $$y'=\frac{x+y}{y-x}$$ and we get the condition $$x\ne y$$